# How prove this two show that $h(x)=\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)dy,g(y)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dx$ is integrable on $x\in[a,b],y\in[c,d]$ respectively

Tags: integration, analysis

let $f(x,y) $ domain $x\in[a,b],y\in[c,d]$, for any  fixed $x$, $f(x,y)$ is integrable on $[c,d]$,and for any $\varepsilon>0$,there exist $\delta>0$ when
$$x_{1},x_{2}\in[a,b],|x_{1}-x_{2}|<\delta$$
then for $\forall y\in[c,d]$,have
$$|f(x_{1},y)-f(x_{2},y)|<\varepsilon$$

show that
$$h(x)=\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)dy,g(y)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dx$$ is integrable on $x\in[a,b],y\in[c,d]$ respectively.and this two integral is equal

Thank you

Comment: $f(x,y):[a,b]\times [c,d]$ makes no sense. $f(x,y)$ is a number (that is, if $f$ is a previously fixed function defined on some sets of ordered pairs...). You should really care about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. By the assumption of uniform continuity (synonymous to continuity on compact interval here) in first variable of $f$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ with $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$ and all $y\in[c,d]$ we have $|f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y)|<\epsilon/(d-c)$. Then:
$$ |h(x_1) - h(x_2)| = |\int_c^d(f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y))dy| \\ \leq \int_c^d|f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y)|dy<\epsilon/(d-c)\cdot \int_c^d dy = \epsilon.$$
Hence $h$ is uniformly continuous, hence integrable.

For integrability of $g$ see Fubini's theorem conditions. Note that at least integrability of $f$ on $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ (or dominance of $f$ by integrable function) is needed to make $g$ integrable and the integrals of $h$ and $g$ equal, that is, $\int_a^bh(x)dx = \int_c^dg(y)dy$. See Theorem 3.7.12 (Fubini–Tonelli theorem for Lebesgue and Riemann
integrable functions) in **Integration and Modern Analysis, by J. Benedetto and W. Czaja**.